# Why is it possible to define a public-access method in a protected-access class?

Tags: java

Consider the following `protected` class containing a `public` method.

```
package my.package;

class MyClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    // myMethod implementation
  }
}
```

Since MyClass is not marked as `public`, it therefore has `protected` access and thus is not accessible outside the package. However, its method `myMethod` is marked as `public`, signifying that it is accessible outside the class.

Since `myMethod` presumably cannot be accessed without accessing `MyClass`, why is it possible to mark `myMethod` as public? Is it because someone might extend `MyClass` from within the package, with a custom `public` class for use outside the package? For example:

```
package my.package;

public MyPublicClass extends MyClass {
  // MyPublicClass implementation
}
```

If so, is there any other use for a `public` method defined within a `protected` class?

Comment: *"Since MyClass is not marked as `public`, it therefore has `protected` and thus is not accessible outside the package"* — Well, the absence of an access modifier is called *package-private*, not *protected*.

Comment: A default or protected class may not be referenced using that type name outside its package, but instances of such a class are definitely usable outside that package, and public methods can be called assuming they are defined in an interface implemented by that class or in a super-class.